# Oracle Coherence and Write-Behind

Tags: database, oracle, caching

I am aware that there is no guarantee of ordering inside a coherence write-behind queue.

If I have data which has referential integrity constraints, is it okay to assume that a failure to write to the database (due to a constraint violation) and a subsequent re-queuing of that write should lead to eventual consistency?

For instance:

- Table **A** has a dependence on a piece of data in Table **B**.
- I have an operation that will create both **B** and **A**.
- IF coherence re-orders my updates to put the creation of **A** *ahead* of the creation of **B**, the creation of **A** will fail.
- In this case, the creation of A should be re-queued and attempted again on the next pass...

Am i missing something?  To me, it seems that this will work correctly, as long as we can tolerate eventual consistency?

Comment: Are you talking about *Oracle Coherence* product ?

Comment: yes, Oracle Coherence - will update

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Coherence Write-Behind is probably a poor match for what you are trying to do, but yes, it can work the way that you have described.

It's might be better to use JPA (e.g. TopLink) with Coherence, and have the transactions play to the database in the manner that the database design expected, and use Coherence to cache the data model that JPA provides.